# How do I add a new column into my query that displays data less that the current date?

Tags: mysql, sql

My current query seen below displays user details and the events they have signed up to, however after they have attended an event I want another column which says WHERE Start_Date < CURDATE() so that there is a split between the current events they have signed up to and the events they have already attended. Any ideas how I can add this to the below query?

```
SELECT users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname, users.user_role,
       GROUP_CONCAT( Events.Event_Name ) AS Event_Names, COUNT(Events.Event_Name) AS Event_Count
FROM users LEFT JOIN 
     user_events
     ON users.id = user_events.id LEFT JOIN
     Events
     ON Events.Event_ID = user_events.Event_ID
GROUP BY users.username, users.user_firstname, users.user_lastname, users.user_role
```

Ideally:

```
| username| user_firstname | user_lastname | user_role | Event_Name |PreEve                               
| M       | jo             | mccann        | employee  | baking,run | fight
```

Comment: Why your `Event_Name` doesn't have a `PreEve` (i.e. `fight`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, u.user_role,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN e.Start_Date < CURDATE() THEN e.Event_Name END) AS Previous_Event_Names, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN e.Start_Date >= CURDATE() THEN e.Event_Name END) AS Future_Event_Names, 
       COUNT(e.Event_Name) AS Event_Count
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     user_events ue
     ON u.id = ue.id LEFT JOIN
     Events e
     ON e.Event_ID = ue.Event_ID
GROUP BY u.username, u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname, u.user_role;
```

`GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Thank you